# How can I display subtitles along with a video with Gradio?

Tags: python, caption, closed-captions, video-subtitles, gradio

I use [Gradio](https://github.com/gradio-app/gradio) to demonstrate some speech recognition system in a video. How can I display subtitles along with a video with Gradio?

Comment: you could create minimal working code.

Comment: It uses some backend that I can't share easily.